# sqllite3 very slow when doing inserts in python of very long strings

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have an 8 column table, mostly text based. When doing an

`INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?)`

One of those values is a string that can have ~ 5000 words. I am inserting 500 of these lines and it takes around 1 minute for it.

When I substitute the long strings for a dummy short one (e.g just "hello") the insert of the 500 lines is instant.

I have to insert 1000s of lines normally and it's going to take 10s of minutes if I proceed like this.

Why is sqlite so slow with long string inserts?

Comment: not sure it matters but is your column TEXT or BLOB?

Comment: it is indeed text